# How do I get this BroadCastReceiver to work?

Tags: android, broadcast, receiver

So I literally tried almost every trick in the book to get this thing running. BUT IN VAIN.
Which is why I just gonna put all that code here. I don't see why this shouldn't work.
No errors or nothing like that. Just the, receiver never fires up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.broadcastmannankatta">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.broadcastmannankatta" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

```
package com.example.broadcastmannankatta;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.
        Toast.makeText(context, "YEAHA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.broadcastmannankatta;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void sendbroadcast(View view) {
        Intent bIntent = new Intent();
        bIntent.setAction("com.example.broadcastmannankatta");
        sendBroadcast(bIntent);
    }
}
```

My UI got a button that fires the sendbroadcast method.

Comment: If you are testing this on Android 8.0 or higher, [implicit broadcasts do not work with manifest-registered receivers](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions).

Comment: So I can't user Broadcasts ?

Comment: I do not know why you would need a broadcast here. But, you could remove the `<intent-filter>` from the `<receiver>` and use an explicit `Intent` (`new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);`) instead of an implicit one.

Comment: I'm trying to use an AlarmManager to repeat the Broadcast every x hours. Since none of that worked out. I;ve been trying to make this basic Broadcast work.

Comment: For periodic work, you might want to consider `WorkManager` rather than using `AlarmManager` directly. If you decide that `AlarmManager` is still the way to go, then a system broadcast is OK, but you will still need to use an explicit `Intent`, as I showed in my previous comment. That will also boost your app security, as with your current approach, any app can send you that broadcast, which may not be a good thing.

Comment: but in the case of Explicit Intents, will my App be able to respond if it's not already running?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212941/discussion-between-jitin-and-commonsware).

Comment: What matters for that is whether your receiver is registered in the manifest. Whether you use an implicit `Intent` or an explicit `Intent` does not affect that behavior... except that an implicit `Intent` will not work on Android 8.0+.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [Android official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#android_80)

Beginning with Android 8.0 (API level 26), the system imposes additional restrictions on manifest-declared receivers.

If your app targets **Android 8.0** or higher, you cannot use the manifest to declare a receiver for most implicit broadcasts (broadcasts that don't target your app specifically). You can still use a context-registered receiver when the user is actively using your app.

So please follow instructions in the link to register to your custom receiver [context-registred receiver](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#context-registered-receivers)

Don't forgot to unregister from your receiver when activity get paused or destoryed.